# Is there a way in Laravel to send an output to both console and log?

Tags: laravel

I am writing a command which has a lot of service information that I need to see during the command is running.

I am outputing this info simply running `echo "some text"`, and that way I can see what happens when running this command. When the same command is run with scheduler I have to log all this info. So I have to duplicate all the same messages with: `Log::info("some text")`.

If I want to avoid duplication I can create a helper class that can have all this, that I then include in all the service classes that are related to this command and use this helper class to avoid code duplication, but I still feel that this is not ideal solution. Is there maybe a built in way in Laravel on how to sent to console output and Log at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

You could add: `->appendOutputTo('path'));` when running your task that execute your command, to store the output messages in your log file. Although, I'm not sure if this will log all console I/O (it will be good to know in case you test it).

---

[Check this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#task-output).

Comment: No, this doesn't address the question. `appendOutputTo()` is something you add to the scheduler, not directly to the console output as you invoke it in the running command, i.e. this doesn't work: `$this->info('initiating command...')->appendOutputTo(/path/to/logfile.log)`